# ldap-account-manager problem

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, dpkg, ldap

I have a problem about ldap-account-manager remove.

Here is errors.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ldap-account-manager -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu php-ldap php-monolog php7.4-ldap

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ldap-account-manager
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.

1 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 74,7 MB disk space will be freed.

(Reading database ... 357061 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ldap-account-manager (7.7-1) ...
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package ldap-account-manager (--remove):
 installed ldap-account-manager package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping

Errors were encountered while processing:
 ldap-account-manager

Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Linux hozer 5.11.0-25-generic #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 17:41:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
$ apt-cache policy ldap-account-manager
ldap-account-manager: 
Installed: 7.7-1 
Candidate: 7.7-1 
Version table: 
*** 7.7-1 100 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 
    6.7-1 500 
       500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages 
       500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you got 7.7 version of [the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ldap-account-manager)?

Comment: Linux hozer 5.11.0-25-generic #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 17:41:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy ldap-account-manager` to the question by editing it.

Comment: ```ldap-account-manager:
  Installed: 7.7-1
  Candidate: 7.7-1
  Version table:
 *** 7.7-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     6.7-1 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove this problematic package forcibly by

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all ldap-account-manager
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: ```$ sudo dpkg -P --force-all ldap-account-manager

(Reading database ... 357061 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing ldap-account-manager (7.7-1) ..

apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.

invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "reload" failed.

dpkg: error processing package ldap-account-manager (--purge):

 installed ldap-account-manager package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

 ldap-account-manager
```

Comment: I can start apache2.service btw

Comment: Then install normal official package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ldap-account-manager=6.7-1` and then retry removal.

Comment: Ok i install 6.7.1 but still can't remove 7.7-1

Comment: Thanks for help solved.

Comment: @hsyn can you share how did you resolve this, I'm having same issue...